# Flutter : how to display an image from its center when landing on the page, using InteractiveViewer?

Tags: flutter, dart

### Context

Let's imagine I'm building an app for an amusement park like Disney World or something. There's a tab where I want to display the map of the place so the visitor can find his way/position. I want the map to be huge for it is more easy to look at.

### What I have

I'm displaying an image that exceed the `width` of my phone screen (on purpose) using `InteractiveViewer` to span and zoom in and out. With spanning the image I'm able to access every pixel of the image. It currently looks like this (I replaced my map with a pikachu image) :

[image]

### What I want

What I would like is that when I land onto this page, the pikachu is automaticcaly displayed centered, like this, where I'd be able just like before to span left and right and zoom to access every desired pixel of the image :

[image]

### My code

```dart
Container(
      height: 650,
      width:  420,
      child: InteractiveViewer(
        constrained: false,
        panEnabled: true,
          child : Container(
            width: 830,
            height: 650,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(5) ,
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/pikachu.png',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          )
      ),
    )
```

### Question

Is there a way to achieve this without relocating the `Container` ? The only solution I can imagine is to move the `Container` to the left, beginning before my phone screen.

Answer (score 0):

> You should try below code just change your image name and app bar name(Dashboard) replace by my
> image name

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Dashboard'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/images/log.png',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> Your Output look like this [image: Image Output]